# xpath getting multiple node values - xml parser using java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

below are the xml file

```
<priority-claims>
          <priority-claim sequence="1" kind="national">
            <document-id document-id-type="maindoc">
             <doc-number>FD0297663</doc-number>
             <date>20070403</date>
            </document-id>
          </priority-claim>
          <priority-claim sequence="2" kind="national">
            <document-id document-id-type="maindoc">
              <doc-number>FD0745459P</doc-number>
              <date>20060424</date>
            </document-id>
            </priority-claim>
</priority-claims>
```

my expected conditions:

1.How can i getting all the node value (i.e `FD0297663, 20070403 and FD0745459P,20060424`)

2.its may be single (i.e Priority -claim tag) or more than a single level is possible

my existing code getting first level value only

```
String priorityNumber = xPath.compile("//priority-claim//doc-number").evaluate(xmlDocument);
 String priorityDate = xPath.compile("//priority-claim//date").evaluate(xmlDocument);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a working example:

- updated the xpath expressions (e.g, `/priority-claims/priority-claim/document-id/doc-number/text()`)
- using `NodeList`

  ```
  NodeList priorityNumbers = (NodeList) xPath.compile("/priority-claims/priority-claim/document-id/doc-number/text()").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
  NodeList priorityDates = (NodeList) xPath.compile("/priority-claims/priority-claim/document-id/date/text()").evaluate(xmlDocument,XPathConstants.NODESET);

  for(int i=0; i<priorityNumbers.getLength();i++){
      System.out.println(priorityNumbers.item(i).getNodeValue());
  }

  for(int i=0; i<priorityDates.getLength();i++){
      System.out.println(priorityDates.item(i).getNodeValue());
  }
  ```

Here is a linkt to a gist with a runnable version: https://gist.github.com/rparree/1c7eb8e9ca928b98418fdb167a2096a3